# Clear focused textbox in multiple textboxes in vb.net using delete key

Tags: vb.net

I want a good example of clearing focused textbox among multiple textboxes using delete key. Please help me providing vb.net code.

The public sub is as such :

```
Public Sub EmptyTxt(ByVal Frm As Form)
    Dim Ctl As Control
    For Each Ctl In Frm.Controls
        'If TypeOf Ctl Is TextBox Then Ctl.Text = ""

    Next
End Sub
```

Then I call this sub from delete keydown event. But it clears all textboxes rather than clearing the focused one.

Comment: What have you tried? Add your code formatted as code with edit link below your question.

Comment: Of course it does because it's written to do so. You need to check in the `For..Each` loop whether the Ctl is focused `If Ctl.Focus Then` do whatever you need to do if it does THEN you should exit the loop using `Exit For` or `Return` if there is no more code to be executed after the `For..Each` block as your snippet suggests.

Comment: Also you could: `Controls.OfType(Of TextBox).Where(Function(a) a.Focus).FirstOrDefault?.Clear()`

Comment: So your actual question is how to access the control that currently has focus.  That's what you should be researching for yourself.  It's not a difficult thing to find.

Comment: Yup... Please provide the code

Answer (score 1):

There's an easier way to do that.

Simply assign all the textbox keyDown events to the same handler.  In that handler, cast sender to a textbox and clear it.

```
Private Sub Form1_Load (sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    For Each tb As TextBox In Controls.OfType(Of TextBox)
        AddHandler tb.KeyDown, AddressOf TbKeyDown
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub TbKeyDown (sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs)
    Dim tb = CType(sender,  TextBox)
    If e.KeyCode = Keys.Delete Then
        tb.Clear()
    End If
End Sub
```